# Pip broken on Debian9

Tags: python, pip

When attempting to install pip on my debian-9 machine I run the following:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

This has worked for years, but now is getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 24226, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 199, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "/tmp/tmpix3aMF/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a workaround. I must run the following instead:

sudo apt-get install python-pip